# Click arrow to reveal more content in application

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to achieve a behavior where user click an arrow that can reveal more content such as more description abort something. It can a recycler view as well where more things can be added dynamically and the list will expand.Right now i do not have any idea how it can be achieved. I tried searching on the internet for solutions and saw a widget called spinner but i do not think it can help me achieve my desired behavior. YouTube does apply similar behavior as well

Below are the pictures which will make my question clear. Any help would be appreciated Thank You

[Before clicking the arrow pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NacIk.png)

[After clicking the arrow pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yb4kN.png)

Answer (score 0):

In your layout.xml include a nested layout that includes a Textview that holds the additional information and set `android:visibility="gone"`. Use an OnClickListener to the button that is meant to expand the view. In the onClick method check if the view is visible or not. If it's not you make it visible, otherwise you set it to gone again.
layout:

```
...
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/chevron"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/chevron"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="your additional info here" 
        android:visibility="gone"/>
...
```

In your Activity:

```
ImageView yourView = findViewById(R.id.chevron);
```

..

```
yourView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (view.getVisibility() == View.Gone) {
                    view.setVisibility(View.Visible);
                } else {
                    view.setVisibility(View.Gone);
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I used for this purpose ExpandbleLayout from this github library 
[ExpandableLayout](https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout). In readMe of the github repo you can find example of using it, you can get similar experience with as in your example, without need to manually create View for arrow and handling the animation. 
You can use it like this :

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:ael_expanded="true"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Some text goes here"
        android:textSize="28sp" />
</com.github.aakira.expandablelayout.ExpandableRelativeLayout>
```

And in your java/kotlin code : do additional logic to expand/collapse call : `expandableLayout.toggle();`.

All the credit goes to the author of the library.
https://github.com/AAkira/ExpandableLayout